# What's the minimal amount of Spring dependencies a library can have?

Tags: java, spring

We have several Java services that are wired together with Spring, and many jars shared between these services that provide @Components.

Due to pervasive copy and pasting, the pom files for the component jars have ended up with the full list of Spring dependencies that the full services require.

What is the recommended minimal set of Spring dependencies that a shared jar should have?

Comment: Take them all out of the POM, add each back if you get compilation, test or deployment errors is the only way to do this correctly.

Comment: True enough; one of the difficulties is that it seems there are many optional dependencies when using Aspects.

Comment: @Adam: Yep, I agree, especially when it comes to optional features like caching (ehcache, etc.). Maybe it's necessary to define your baseline first - identify all libs available and try to find out which  JARs _may_ need them. As I said in my answer it might become a reverse-engineering nightmare

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**What is the recommended minimal set of Spring dependencies that a shared jar should have?**

I don't think there is one as it depends on the scope of your shared JAR. If the JAR contains classes covering aspects of different layers (persistence, presentation, etc.) you may need "everything". In the worst case and if it's really complex, reverse-engineering may be your last resort: remove all dependencies not required at compile time and then test, test, test... I know - painful :-)

Comment: Using Maven to visualize dependencies might help make that process easier.

Answer (score 2):

None. Spring being non-invasive does not require adding any compile-time dependencies. But when you use more specific features:

- the stereotype annotations are in spring-context, if you use them (@Component).
- @Autowired is in spring-beans
- for everything else - it depends on what you use

Note that this is for compile time. When you run it you will need at least spring-core, but that should be defined by the application that uses ghe jars

Answer (score 1):

Typically it is two:  Spring core and Spring security.  If you are not using Spring security than core will be plenty too get you through.

Comment: @andyb you would be amazed how many people incorrectly write unit tests, so I omitted it.

Comment: We unit test our components via JUnit, not sure what spring-test adds to party, to tell the truth.

Comment: @Woot4Moo totally agree. Just thought I'd mention it. Guess it depends if you have persistence layer tests that use it. Sounds like you are testing components independently though :-)

Comment: There is a spring-context that using the SpringJunitRunner to pass information around.  The issue is it is technically not a unit test at that point, it becomes an integration test

Comment: Spring Test makes it possible to access configuration context via annotation, makes database tests transactional, etc.